# Products are Couniversal in CRing

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory

While reading Y. Diers text "Categories of Commutative Algebra" he defines a Zariski category which is a general context in which to  construct schemes. One of the axioms is that products are couniversal. In trying to prove that the category of commutative rings is a Zariski category I got stuck on showing this. 
Precisely, if we are given a ring morphism $f\colon A\times B\to C$ the pushouts $q_A\colon A\to A\otimes_{A\times B}C$, $q_B\colon B\to C\otimes_{A\times B}B$ of $\pi_A$, $\pi_B$ along $f$ give us $(q_A,q_B, C)$ as a product.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Just didn't see how to proceed in the proof. I provided the context above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I_A = \ker (A \times B \to A)$ and $I_B = \ker (A \times B \to B)$. Clearly, $I_A \cdot I_B = I_A \cap I_B = \{ 0 \}$ and $I_A + I_B = A \times B$. Let $C I_A$ and $C I_B$ be the corresponding ideals in $C$. It is not hard to check that $A \otimes_{A \times B} C \cong C / C I_A$ and $C \otimes_{A \times B} B \cong C / C I_B$. Thus, the claim is that the canonical comparison $C \to C / C I_A \times C / C I_B$ is an isomorphism.

By the Chinese remainder theorem, it suffices to show that $C I_A \cdot C I_B = \{ 0 \}$ and $C I_A + C I_B = C$. But this is clear, so we are done.